# Performing supervised classification with Landsat 7 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, land-classification, landsat-7

I am trying to perform landcover classification of Shanghai using JavaScript in Google Earth Engine. I am a complete beginner at this and I have been going through many tutorials trying to figure things out. My problem is that many of these tutorials are aimed at Landsat 8 but I need to use Landsat 7 and it covers the time period I need.

I have made my training points and now need to create the training data, so far my code is as follows:

```
//filter image collection
/**
* Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
* @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2015-12-31')
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.setCenter(121.51520494843749,31.22304570235914, 10);
Map.addLayer(dataset.median(), visParams);

//merge the feature collections
var newfc = Urban.merge(Water).merge(Vegetation);
//print (newfc);

//create training data by overlaying the training points on the image
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6_VCID_1', 'B6_VCID_2', 'B7'];
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
    collection: newfc, 
    properties: ['landcover'], 
    scale: 30
});
```

When I run this it says that image is not defined (after var training), which is true, I have not defined it, but when I try other things (for instance cloudMaskL457.select) it says that cloudMaskL457.select is not a function.

I don't know how to get past this, please help!